# native C++: WSDL proxy generation library

Tags: c++, web-services, mfc, wsdl

It is necessary to communicate to WebService from C++ MFC application. I can add reference to the service, but wsdl is generated for if simple types are used only. Attempt to generate proxy for methods with complex types returns an error:

> does not support extension of complexType

Here is a suggestions to fix that: http://support.xignite.com/entries/168861-getting-around-the-sdl1030-sproxy-exe-does-not-support-extension-of-complextype

My intention is to generate with some WSDL proxy generation library.

Question: could you please advise good library for WSDL proxy generation? On the linked page http://ws.apache.org/axis/ is advised library suggested. Did anybody used it? Is it fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is [gsoap](http://gsoap2.sourceforge.net/) what you are looking for?  It can generate both client and server sides of a Web Service in C or C++.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you please look what is wrong with its performance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329666/gsoap-half-minute-on-operation-why-so-slow

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your target platforms check out [WsUtil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd430644%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) which is part of the [Windows Web Services API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd430435%28VS.85%29.aspx)

From the MSDN page:

> Windows Web Services API (WWSAPI)
>   offers C/C++ application programming
>   interface (API) for building SOAP
>   based web services and clients to
>   them.

Comment: Target platform is Windows. Thanks, will try